# Show for all $ \varepsilon>0 $ there exist's $ R\geq 0 $ such that $ \mu([-R,R])>1-\varepsilon $.

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Let $ \mu $ a measure on $ (\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}) $ with $ \mu(\mathbb{R})=1 $.Show for all $ \varepsilon>0 $ there exist's $ R\geq 0 $ such that $ \mu([-R,R])>1-\varepsilon $.

It is intuitively clear for me but I have no idea except to strive for a contradiction. So asume there exist's $ \varepsilon>0 $ such that for all $ R\geq 0 $ it is: $ \mu([-R,R])\leq1-\varepsilon $. I also know that a measure behaves monotone which means for all $ R\geq 0 $ it is $ [-R,R]\subseteq \mathbb{R} $ so $ \mu([-R,R])\leq \mu(\mathbb{R})=1 $. But what should I do these fact's?

Comment: Hint: $\mu(\bigcup_{n = 1}^\infty A_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \mu(A_n)$ for all increasing sequences ($A_1 \subseteq A_2 \subseteq \ldots$) of measurable sets $(A_n)$. Note that what you wrote is equivalent to $\lim_{R \to \infty} \mu([-R, R]) = 1$.

Comment: I don't get it how this can help me.

Comment: Ah I have an idea: I consider $1=\mu(\mathbb{R})=\lim_{R\to \infty} \mu([-R,R])\leq \lim_{R\to \infty} 1-\varepsilon=1-\varepsilon $. But then $ \varepsilon=0 $ which is a contradiction.

Comment: @hallo97 it's not correct. Where does the inequality come from?

Comment: It comes from my assumption that  there exist's ε>0 such that for all R≥0 it is: μ([−R,R])≤1−ε

Comment: Once you have $\lim_{R \to \infty} \mu([-R, R]) = 1$, the conclusion is an immediate consequence from the definition of the limit.